# What is the proper way of pointing to (pointer to structure)?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have 2 pointers (**a** and **b**).
**a** is my main pointer and I allocated it by `malloc`.
**b** is just a pointer and must point to **a**.
 I did it as below:

**First code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct var
{
    int i;
} var;

void main()
{
    var *a = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var));
    var *b = a;

    // Checking what I did is correct and pointers point to each other
    a->i = 123;
    b->i = 456;
    printf("%d %d", a->i, b->i); // output: 456 456
}
```

But I'm not pretty sure about the way I used pointer **b**, cause I can get the same result when I use extra allocation for **b**. See below:

**Second code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct var
{
    int i;
} var;

void main()
{
    var *a = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var));
    var *b = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var)); // extra allocation
    b = a;

    // Checking what I did is correct and pointers point to each other
    a->i = 123;
    b->i = 456;
    printf("%d %d", a->i, b->i); // output: 456 456
}
```

**Q:** Is **second code** correct or just memory-wasting? Should I use allocation when I just want pointing to another pointer?
**PS:** I know my question is basic but I googled a lot and found nothing.

Comment: Your second example leaks memory. The first example just copies a pointer, and is the correct approach.

Comment: You can add also a hundred more allocations. Each one will happily cause your code to throw away the previous value and only keep the last assigned value, i.e. `b = a;`

Comment: Re “`a`… I allocated it…” You did not allocate `a`. You allocated memory for `a` to point to. Do yourself a favor for future learning and programming and do not think of pointers as associated with the memory they point to. They are simply objects on their own that have address as values. You use them to manage memory, but they are not glued to it.

Comment: Re “`b`… must point to `a`”: No, you want `b` to point to the same memory that `a` points to. If `b` pointed to `a`, it would point to the pointer that is `a`; it would not point to the memory that `a` points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets go over the statements one by one, with some drawings to show where the variables are pointing.

```
var *a = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var));
```

That will be something like this:

```
+---+      +-----+
| a | ---> | ??? |
+---+      +-----+
```

<sub>[I put `???` because the memory isn't initialized, and its contents is indeterminate]</sub>

Following that we have:

```
var *b = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var)); // extra allocation
```

And now you have:

```
+---+      +-----+
| a | ---> | ??? |
+---+      +-----+

+---+      +-----+
| b | ---> | ??? |
+---+      +-----+
```

Now you have two memory areas, one from each call to `malloc`, and `a` and `b` are pointing to one each.

Lastly the assignment:

```
b = a;
```

Now it's like this:

```
+---+         +-----+
| a | ---+--> | ??? |
+---+    |    +-----+
         |
+---+    |    +-----+
| b | --/     | ??? |
+---+         +-----+
```

The assignment makes `b` point to the exact same memory as `a` is pointing to. The memory allocated by your second call to `malloc` will be lost, and you will have a *memory leak*.

---

If you *really* want `b` to be a pointer to the variable `a`, you need to make it a pointer to a pointer, and use the pointer-to operator `&` to get a pointer to `a`:

```
var **b = &a;
```

With such a definition then it will look like this:

```
+---+     +---+      +-----+
| b | --> | a | ---> | ??? |
+---+     +---+      +-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
var *a = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var));
var *b = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var)); // extra allocation
b = a;
```

produces a memory leak. At first a memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer b

```
var *b = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var)); // extra allocation
```

and then the pointer b was reassigned with the value stored in the pointer a.

```
b = a;
```

So now the both pointers point to the same object.

The difference between the two programs is that this record in the second program

```
var *b = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var)); // extra allocation
```

apart from the declaration of the pointer b has no effect except of the produced memory leak. A memory was allocated and its address at once was lost. So the memory becomes inaccessible.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the point in pointers. They are variables like your `int` and do not need allocation to hold a value.

```
    var *a = (var *) malloc(sizeof(var));
```

What you do here is create a memory location for the struct, similar to `var my_struct;` (except it is in different memory), and then saving its location to `a` so `var *a = &my_struct`.

`var *a` itself doesn't need to be allocated, cause it is already allocated when you declared it, as is `var *b`, and so you can make `b` point to `a` without any further steps to prepare it.

---

So you could for your example code do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct var
{
    int i;
} var;

void main()
{
    var my_struct;
    var *a = &my_struct;
    var *b;
    b = a;

    // Checking what I did is correct and pointers point to each other
    a->i = 123;
    b->i = 456;
    printf("%d %d", a->i, b->i); // output: 456 456
}
```